# How to remove blank space on the menu bar?

Tags: macos, menu-bar, google-apps

For some reason I have a blank space on my menubar, It doesn't happen on my second screen, and when i click it disappears but appears in the other screen and so forth.

I haven't done anything to the system like trying to remove the spotlight icon or that sort of thing.
I have OS X 10.9.4

[image: space in menu bar]

I've tried removing all other apple icons and this happens: [image: http://i.gyazo.com/2126339e067c6c9b680ce623d58eef2a.png]

When  I activate istat menu, the issue goes away temporarily but I'd rather not use istat forever.

Are there any other solutions to this?

Comment: I'd like to ask everyone to resist accusing anyone of further rudeness. I'd be glad to set up a private chat if that helps people work out any feelings that may be causing them to react in an emotional way. With the edits, I think this thread can help others, but negative comments are harming the mood. Big thanks for tolerance while we clean up things... (the mods)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it was LittleSnitch, even though it had it "show status in menu bar" disabled, on one screen it will always show that empty space.

Comment: Excellent sleuthing - thanks for persevering the rough spot where down votes were arriving. Hopefully the question will accumulate some upvotes in time.

Comment: Parallels Desktop 10 does this as well. I just cmd-dragged it to the end so it would be invisible.

Answer (score 5):

### Restart your menubar

This might be due to some error within the placements of the icons in your menubar. You can restart your menubar and your icons will 'reload' and settle correctly.

Run the following in Terminal to reload the menubar:

```
killall -KILL SystemUIServer
```

Comment: I know this command very well and done it over and over tried everything it does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Some applications (like Google drive) will reserve the space to the right of it for messages.

Comment: but this space didn't appear before, it just popped up one day and it doesn't happen in my other macbook which also has google drive. I've never hear of such thing.
doesn't explain either why it disappears when i click it and appears in my second monitor and viceversa.